# making your posts password-protected by default

Tags: wordpress, function, passwords, categories

I originally wanted to be able to password protect a category.  At the very least I wanted it to be password-protected, but preferably a username and password login.  Since I have been unsuccessful for days at finding a solution I have now resorted to using WordPress's built-in password protection for posts.

The issue I am having is I will be posting via e-mail and in order to have these posts password-protected I need to login to Wordpress and then manually select password-protected and enter a password in the dashboard.

I would like to be able to have all posts that appear in a specific category be password-protected with the same password by default.  Eliminating having to log in to Wordpress and manually select password protect.

I know there is a function `<?php post_password_required( $post ); ?>` that I need to use but I am not sure how to implement it or where.

Answer (score 2):

```
    add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', function( $data, $postarr ){
    if ( 'book' == $data['post_type'] && 'auto-draft' == $data['post_status'] ) {
        $data['post_password'] = wp_generate_password();
    }
    return $data;
}, '99', 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this WordPress StackExchange answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51364/12615). Tested only with a regular dashboard. Publishing via email has to be tested, but I suppose the hook gets called in this kind of posting.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post' );

function wpse51363_save_post( $post_id ) {

    //Check it's not an auto save routine
     if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
          return;

    //Check it's not an auto save routine
     if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) 
          return;

    //Perform permission checks! For example:
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) 
          return;

    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms(
        $post_id, 
        'category', 
        array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) 
    );

    if( in_array ( 'the-category-slug', $term_list ) )
    {
        // Unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post' );

        // Call wp_update_post update, which calls save_post again. 
        wp_update_post( array( 
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_password' => 'default-password' ) 
        );

        // Re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse51363_save_post' );
    }
}
```